# How can I communicate between a Unity application and a regular Android application?

Tags: android, android-ndk, unity-game-engine, native-code, native-methods

I'm an Android developer who is working with a Unity developer. Our goal is to create somehow a "bridge" communication to send messages between my Android background Service/thread to the Unity exported game (both running on the same device...)

For now, the only solution we've found to implement such communication is by directly by opening TCP Sockets between the two apps based on the localhost.

I know also that it's supposed to be possible to somehow create native C functions in Unity which can be reachable from my Android app, but I haven't found any good explanation of how to do that.

Is there a way to develop the Unity game to somehow expose the Android API?
Is there any other way, besides the solution I've mentioned, to create this kind of communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Unity Building plugins for Android](http://panther.unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html)

Answer (score 2):

you can check my tutorial for your problem, might help you ! ;)

http://jeanmeyblum.weebly.com/1/post/2014/02/communication-between-an-android-app-and-unity.html

Comment: thanks, actually that what I eventually did at that time I asked the question.   sending broadcasts that UnityActivity receives...